# VBA Excel: Runtime error 13 when getting range content into an array - long cell content

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get the content of a row into a 1 dimensional VBA array. I used the very basic way to get the content of the row, by:

1- assigning the range content to an Excel Variant

2- transposing the array twice, to get it from 2 dimensional to 1 dimensional

This works fine in almost all my lines, but I am getting a runtime error 13 'Type mismatch' when one of the cells has a content longer than 255 caracters.

Do you by any chance have any advice on how to solve this issue?

```vb
Dim rowContent As Variant 
Dim lineCount As Long
Dim curLine As Long

lineCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(editWSName).Range("A:A")) - 2
For curLine = 3 To lineCount + 2
        rowContent = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(editWSName).Range(Cells(curLine, 2), Cells(curLine, colCount))))
        ...
Next curLine
```

Comment: try `Dim rowContent() As Variant `

Comment: Don't use `Transpose`. Create another array yourself and populate it from the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to get through this problem as recommended by Rory, I added a pivot array to populate my final array.

My solution is the following:

```vb
    Dim lineCount As Long
    Dim colCount As Long
    Dim tempArray As Variant ' tableau temporaire
    Dim rowContent() As String ' array contenant le contenu de la ligne courante
    Dim i As Long
    ...

    lineCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(editWSName).Range("A:A")) - 2
    colCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(editWSName).Range("2:2"))
    fieldCodes = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(editWSName).Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(2, colCount))))
    ReDim rowContent(1 To colCount - 1)

    ...

    For curLine = 3 To lineCount + 2
        tempArray = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(editWSName).Range(Cells(curLine, 2), Cells(curLine, colCount))
        For i = 1 To UBound(tempArray, 2)
            rowContent(i) = tempArray(1, i)
        Next i
        Set controlDict = controlLine(rowContent, fieldCodes)
        ...
    Next curLine
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple way to get the content of a **single row** into a one-dimensional array:

```
Sub RowToArray()
    Dim rng As Range, s As String
    Dim msg As String

    Set rng = Rows("1:1").Cells
    s = Chr(1)

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        arr = Split(.TextJoin(s, True, rng), s)
    End With

    msg = LBound(arr) & vbCrLf & UBound(arr)
    For Each a In arr
        msg = msg & vbCrLf & a
    Next a

    MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

[image]

As you see, cell **D1**, which contains more than 300 characters, is fully captured.

Comment: Thanks Gary! I did not use your solution for my specific problem, but I have bookmarked it for further usage. Regards,